# Parse Android: understanding cloud code and deploy

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My app is simple as it requires four steps

**Step 1:** 
UserA can create a questionnaire and send it to userB.

**Step 2:** 
UserB receives the questionnaire with three options represented in radio button

**Step 3:** 
UserB chooses the preferable answer that presented in radio button and click submit button

**Step 4:** 
Upon clicking submit button userA receives an email with given answer from userB

However, I used parse for this app and I just started recently learning about cloud code and how to use it since ***I am trying to fetch sender's (UserA) email from User table*** but still I am not getting the desired results as I feel I am missing something

**My main.js**

```
   Parse.Cloud.define("getEmail", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var senderName = userEmail.get("senderId");
    userQuery.equalTo("email", request.params.email);
    userQuery.get("email", {
success: function(userEmail) {
    // the object was retrieved 
    if ( email == senderName) {
        status.message(email + "found");
        return getEmail.save;
    } 
     else {
        status.message("Invalid email address");
    }
}, 
  error: function(object, error) {
status.error("something went wrong")
}

});
});
```

**My android, cloud code function**

```
private void callCodeCloud() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("objectId", objectId);
    params.put("email", email);

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getEmail", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {

        public void done(String email, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Vote Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}


private String returnVoteAnswer() {
    int nIdRadio = radioVoteGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (nIdRadio == R.id.optionone) {
        optionONE.setText(mO);
        callCodeCloud();
    }
    else if (nIdRadio == R.id.optiontwo) {
        optionTWO.setText(mT);
        callCodeCloud();
    }
    else if (nIdRadio == R.id.optionthree) {
        optionTHREE.setText(mH);
        callCodeCloud();
    }
    else{
        }
    return null;
    }
```

I have been really struggling with this for a while now and I need guidance please. It will be really great achievement for me and fresher by finishing this app as this problem has become an obstacle for me in finishing this app. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I see several problems with your cloud code function. Instead of  pointing them out, I would prefer providing a suggested solution. But first I need to understand what you're trying to achieve. You're trying to get the sender's email, but based on what?

Comment: I am trying to get sender's email the who is creating the survey so he/she can receive the answer from userB.

Comment: So which email is provided to the function in request.params.email ?

Comment: I am trying to put the sender's email but not sure if that was the right way

Comment: If you in this function have both the sender's email and the sender object, what are you then querying for?

Comment: I am trying to querying the sender's email in this function but it is not perform the work I want not sure what went wrong. But from your question, does that mean I need to query only the sender's email but not the sender's object?

Comment: I just still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You say you need the sender's email, but you already have that AND the sender object. So why are you querying at all?

Comment: Most likely I did not fully understand cloud code function. I thought I do need to query them. Thank you for your patient with me, I am really grateful. Sorry, I am new to the whole cloud function thing. Does that mean I do not need to query them? How do I confirm this is the sender's email though?